# Why I can not use Map in dynamic query

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

```
Map<Id, Account> maps = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Account acc : [Select Id from Account])
{  
    maps.put(acc.Id, acc);
}

String s = 'Select Id from Account Where Id IN : maps.keySet()' ;

List<Account> acc =   Database.query(s);
System.debug('@@' + acc);
```

> Line: 9, Column: 1 System.QueryException: unexpected token: '('

Comment: Map<Id, Account> maps = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Account acc : [Select Id from Account])
{  
    maps.put(acc.Id, acc);
}

String s = 'Select Id from Account Where Id IN : ' ;
s = s+ maps.keySet();
List<Account> acc =   Database.query(s);
System.debug('@@' + acc);
 
Its also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, We have to store `map.KeySet()` or `map.values()` in either list/set and then use that set and list over there.
Because , we can use variable and collection in dynamic SOQL and `map.keySet()` / `map.values()` are the method of collection type(map).

Comment: i flagged this answer for moderation. Because there is best answer given by @sfdcweb which is perfect.

Comment: @BaskaranS this isn't something moderators can change.

Answer (score 11):

Use an extra set variable

```
set<Id> setAccountIds = new set<Id>();

Map<Id, Account> maps = new Map<Id, Account>([Select Id from Account]);
setAccountIds.addAll(maps.keySet());
String s = 'Select Id from Account Where Id IN :setAccountIds ';

List<Account> acc =   Database.query(s);
System.debug('@@' + acc);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible using map only ?

Comment: @YogeshGupta what I think looks we can't use directly map's keyset.. We need to store somewhere and then use in dynamic soql

Comment: @YogeshGupta is my ans different than Neha's Answer ?

Answer (score 3):

from the Apex Developer guide

"You can use simple bind variables in dynamic SOQL query strings:

for more info about the binding

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm